# How to get font information (ttf, otf) on the command line with fontconfig's fc-scan utility for my system language?

Tags: fonts, language-support

I want to get information about fonts (ttf or otf), like the family name and the style.

If possible, I don't want to install extra software like `otfinfo`. Since `fontconfig` is installed everywhere, a good option seems to be

```
fc-scan --format "%{family} %{style}\n" font.ttf
```

However, the output is

```
Bookman Old Style Cursiva,kurzíva,kursiv,Πλάγια,Italic,Kursivoitu,Italique,Dőlt,Corsivo,Cursief,Kursywa,Itálico,Курсив,İtalik,Poševno,Etzana
```

where the style is in all the different languages the font supports. How can I restrict the output of `fc-scan` to the system language or English?

Desired output would be `Bookman Old Style Italic` for the case above.

Answer (score 4):

To get the font information in the system language, use

```bsh
    fc-scan --format "%{fullname[$(( $(sed -E 's/^(.*)en.*/\1/;s/[^,]//g' <<<"$(fc-scan --format "%{fullnamelang}\n" /mnt/Fonts/bookosb.ttf)" | wc -c) -1 ))]}\n" /mnt/Fonts/bookosb.ttf
```